# MVC3 Inconsistent JSON/DateTime Behaviour between JsonResult and JsonValueProviderFactory?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I recently upgraded one of my project from MVC2 to MVC3 and adjusted some code accordingly. One issue I enountered is the JSON and DateTime issue.

I have a very simple code to demo, the idea is very straight forward that I return JSON from controller, client side JavaScript receives as is and post back to another action method to compare data.

My view model used as data container is

```
public class JsonViewModel {
    public int IntegerValue {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StringValue {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeValue {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a controller with 2 action methods, one to generate JSON data and one to receive JSON data:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetJsonData() {
        JsonViewModel data = new JsonViewModel
        {
            IntegerValue = 99,
            StringValue = "This is test string",
            DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now
        };

        return new JsonResult { ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, Data = data };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiveJsonData(JsonViewModel data) {
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

The view code is very simple as well,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeClass>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<link type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/site1.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js") %>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="JSON Test" id="btnJson" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnJson').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/GetJsonData/",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (request, error) {
                    alert("readyState: " + request.readyState + "\nstatus: " + request.status);
                    alert("responseText: " + request.responseText);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "/Home/ReceiveJsonData/",
                        cache: false,
                        data: jsonData,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (result) {
                            //alert(result);
                        },
                        error: function (request) {
                            alert("readyState: " + request.readyState + "\nstatus: " + request.status);
                            alert("responseText: " + request.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expect is that the object genrated and searilzed in `GetJsonData` action method should be same as `ReceiveJsonData` action method. But the actual behaviour is that integer and string values are persisted, but `datetime` value is reset.

Any clue why?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got an answer from http://forums.asp.net/t/1689952.aspx/1 which work perfectly to me.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could do something like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\/Date\(\d+\)/g, function (a) { return '\\' + a + '\\'; });
```

And it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. During tests i've realized that JSON.stringify removes "\" from "\/Date(xxxxx)\/" and MVC is not able to deserialize it. The solution is to enforce different type of DateTime serialization. Instead of returning JsonResult I do something like this:
`var json = JsonConvert.ExportToString(data); return Content(json,"application/json");`

JsonConvert is a Jayrock library class. It stores DateTime values in XML format which is understandable for MVC. Hope that helps